# Bash: How to look for a mouse in Bash

Tags: bash, mouse, tablet

I was wondering if there was a way to use bash scripts to check whether the system has a mouse (computer) or not (tablet), not as in where the mouse is on the screen but as in to detect if it's a tablet or if you're using a mouse on the device...

Uses of this:
Making a desktop work better on Tablets automatically

Comment: `xinput --list`?

Comment: It worked in part of my script shown below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make a working script for Mice and Touchpads alike as well as detection of touch screen properly, here's what I did:

```
#/bin/bash -e

ls /dev/input/by-id/*mouse && echo "Desktop Mode" && exit
xinput --list | grep TouchPad && echo "Desktop Mode" || echo "Tablet Mode"
```

Answer (score 1):

This kind of information is slightly dependent on the specific Linux distribution.

Following a couple of commands that may help...

`ls /dev/input/by-id/*mouse && echo "yes" || echo "no"`

`cat /proc/bus/input/devices | grep -E 'Name|Handler'`

`cat /proc/bus/input/devices | awk -v RS="" '/TouchPad/ {print "laptop";last}'`

`xinput --list`

`sudo dmidecode --string chassis-type`
--> this last one will return something like "Laptop", "Notebook" "Portable", "Sub Notebook", "Main Server Chassis", ...
(`cat /sys/class/dmi/id/chassis_type` to avoid sudo)

Comment: Ok, will try it, though, will trackpads count as mice in that?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/611579)

Comment: Upvoted it only because of it is useful in the script I figured out...

Comment: @Zacharee1, my "answer" was in fact rather poor... I changed it to be more clear and useful.

Answer (score 1):

bluedxca93ish alternative without the need of exit.

```
if [ -n "$(ls /dev/input/by-id/*mouse 2>/dev/null | grep -i 'usb\|PS\|COM')" ]; then echo "Bluedxca93 found a mice thats nice";fi

if [ -n "$(xinput --list | grep TouchPad)" ]; then echo "Bluedxca93 found a damn tablet";fi
```

That is certainly slower than your method but not that bash version dependant as yours i fear.
Also only two lines.